# Logical Volume now has two segments after lvextend

Tags: lvm

My ubuntu machine has an LVM2 Volume Group (VG) containing a number of Logical Volumes (LV).  The VG is composed of 2 Physical Volumes (PV).  All of my LVs were created striped with 2 stripes each.  Running `sudo lvs --segments` was showing the list of LVs all having only one segment.  I've recently extended one of my LVs to increase it's size by 50G, using `sudo lvextend -i2 -L+50G VGname/LVname` and now I've noticed that `sudo lvs --segments` is showing 2 segements for the LV which I extended.  When viewd using the LVM GUI I can see that the two segements exist at different locations on each PV.  I imagine that this may reduce IO performance for that LV.  So I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to extend an LV which maintains just 1 segment?
2. Now that I ahve two segments is there a way to merge the segments into 1 again?

Thanks - JJB

Answer (score 0):

LVM is an abstraction layer to get you away from PVs and best run on RAID(0+1) or RAID5 systems where you have an enormous amount of disks and the LV which you build upon is more important then the PV.

And if you have spare PVs you can then move your LVs around as you see fit and as need shrinks or grows.

So if you're running on one PC with 4 disks, and you're never going to grow to 10, LVM is something extra to know just for the heck of it, but has no real tangential benefits.  It's always good to put on your CV though!  ;-)

If you're more worried about system performance then logical groupings and disk management, or only have 2 disks then just use tried-and-trusted disks, partitions and file systems.  :-)

Comment: The VG i've mentioned above is used as a virual machine storage pool.  I use Qemu / KVM to run a noumber of VMs.  Each VM has a Logical Volume for storage.  LVM allows me to take stapshots of the VMs + other benefits.  So, my VG may very well expand in future to include more physical volumes but for now just has two with each logical volume being striped over both of them.  I know what LVM is all about - I'm really trying to find out how to merge a multi-segment LV into a single segment LV.  If it's possible at all.

Comment: Move it to a spare PV that is big enough to hold the two segments...